# How to break the input from dictionary python

Tags: python-3.x

members
I am facing  problem to do the following in Python. I have input as follows

```
Input {(1, 2): [(2,), (1,)], (1, 3): [(3,), (1,)], (2, 3): [(2,), (3,)], 
(1,): [1], (2,): [2], (3,): [3], (1, 2, 3): [(1, 2), (3,)]}
```

Now the output should be

```
(1,2,3=(2),(1),(3).
```

It needs to check the Input key (1,2,3) and its corresponding value is [(1,2),(3)] again it looks for (1,2) in input array and it finds value corresponding to (1,2) is (2) and (1). Any idea how to do it.My code is not working perfectly.

I need your help regarding this.

```
def OptimalPartition(L=[],tempdict=dict()):
global ret
L=tuple(L)
chk0=tempdict.get(L[0])
chk1=tempdict.get(L[1])
if len(tuple([chk0]))==1:
   print(L[0])
   ret.append(chk0)
else:
   OptimalPartition(list(L[0]),tempdict)
if len(tuple([chk1]))==1:
   print(L[1])
   ret.append(chk1)
else:
   OptimalPartition(list(L[1]),tempdict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just want to unpack each key-value entry indefinitely within the same dictionary.

This small snippet will let you do that, the formatting is up to you to get right.

```
d = {(1, 2): [(2,), (1,)], (1, 3): [(3,), (1,)], (2, 3): [(2,), (3,)], 
     (1,): [1], (2,): [2], (3,): [3], (1, 2, 3): [(1, 2), (3,)]}  


def unpack(d,key):
    if len(d[key]) == 1:
        return tuple(d[key])
    ret = tuple()
    for k in d[key]:
        if k in d:
            ret += unpack(d,k)
        else:
            # This happens if the value for the key has
            # one value, in that case we simply add that 
            # to the returning tuple
            ret += (k,)
    return ret


for key in d:
    ret = unpack(d,key)
    print('  key, ret: ',key,', ',ret)
```

Comment: Thank you @zeroth . You made my life easier.

Comment: @NARAYANCHANGDER Please follow the form of stackexchange, tick the answer button if it resolved your question, and tick up any questions/answer you may find interesting or excellently posed.

Comment: I will try this method.Ok i will follow this rule @zeroth

Comment: Here problem is when the key and value is same. In that case the program runs continuously till maximum recursion depth reached. For example d:{(1,2):[(1,2)],(1,2,3):[(1,2),(3)]} and output should be (1,2,3)=(1,2)(3)

Comment: @NARAYANCHANGDER see now, it should do as you suspected.

Comment: thanks again @zeroth. Its working as i expected. Please don mind i am not good at Python programming. I should change the code.